# How to calculate height of div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in such a situation that I have to set height of a div depends on the amount of content in it, I can't give `min-height` in it. I know we can calculate height of div by :

```
$("#divid").height();
```

So is there any way we can calculate height of a div without having height parameter in it and give height to that div depends on the amount of content in it.

I hope I explained it clearly.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "without having height parameter"?

Comment: I mean by that is <div style="height:450px;"></div> . If i don't have height parameter in this then how can i calculate height of this div?

Comment: @RavinderSingh That should work just by using `.height()`. It calculates fine without the attribute. Also, divs automatically fit their content vertically, so what are you doing that breaks that behavior?

Comment: This [**link**](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) is not related but might help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you said, with `.height()`, there does not need to be an actual height defined for that to be used. here is a jsfiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nWb5j/

Answer (score 6):

Your wording is a bit confusing, but I think you are asking how to calculate the size of the content inside a div even if the div has a different height applied. For that you can use the element's [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight).

```
$('#divid')[0].scrollHeight
```

If you just want to know how to calculate the height of an element even though it has no attribute/style for height, you can just use what you have written in the question. `.height()` computes the height of the element directly from the browser rendered values, not from the attributes specifically.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways doing it:

```
$("#parent").height($("#child").outerHeight(true));
//-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^--^^^^-----outerHeight(true) will give
//---------------------------------------------------you the total height 
//---------------------------------------------------including top bottom margins
```

more info .outerHeight : **http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/**

and if your html is:

```
<div style="height:450px;"></div>
```

then you can use this to get the height:

```
$("#parent").css('height'); // this will give you the 450px
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery calculates the height, using `.height()`](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4juq/2/), even when there is no height setting (via CSS or otherwise) on the element.