# How can I calculate 10% of a div? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/rg28hk2n/

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div>

</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var height= $('div').outerHeight();
    alert(height);

    });
```

Currently I have retained a variable height of my div.
I want to retain a variable, 10% of the height of my div.

Comment: Did you try `var height= $('div').outerHeight()*10/100;` ?

Comment: `var tenpct = height * 0.1` ?   Am I missing something?

Comment: [updatedfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rg28hk2n/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate height of div in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097994/how-to-calculate-height-of-div-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var height = $('div').outerHeight() * 0.1;
  alert(height);

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple math problem:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var height= $('div').outerHeight()/10;
        alert(height);

        });
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ewee1wt/)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple math problem...
Multiply the height by `0.1`
`var height= $('div').outerHeight() * .1;`